# doctrine 2 left join

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

how can i do in Doctrine 2 using ->from(), ->leftjoin...

something like this

```
select c.* from category left join domande as d on d.category_id = c.id left join age as a on d.age_id = a where a.age > 30 and a.id is not null
```

i keep getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Semantical Error] line 0, col 63 near 'd ORDER BY c.ordine': Error: Identification Variable Entities\Domanda used in join path expression but was not defined before.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a typo in your query -- notice that the spelling is different for "Domande" and "Domanda" in the two places you have it in your question. Also, your SQL doesn't mention the ORDER BY clause but the error message does.

Here is your query written in DQL and including the ORDER BY clause referenced in the error message.

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT c FROM Entities\Category LEFT JOIN c.domande d LEFT JOIN d.age a 
     WHERE a.age > 30 AND a.id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY c.ordine');
$results = $query->getResult();
```